# How can I get this goblin out of the ground?

Tags: wii-u, darksiders-2

I'm stuck in the second room of the lost temple in Darksiders II. In this room, I am supposed to maneuver a golem into a socket to open the next door. However, I fooled a bit around with the golem and suddenly, the golem moved some six feet into the ground. Thus, the golem is now buried literally up to its throat in the ground.

I can still mount the golem and can let him punch through the ground, but it's impossible to move him. Is there any possibility to get the golem out of the ground? Unfortunately, the game had already auto-saved the position of the golem when I reloaded the save state, so that it reappered in the ground at the exact same place.

Is there any way to reset the golem's position? I tried leaving the area and reentering, but this didn't help either.

If there is no possibility to resolve this issue and my save game is rendered useless by this bug, can anyone provide a WiiU save state at approximately this place in the game?

Answer (score 1):

The game has auto save but it also has saves at each main campaign point. Try searching your save data for a save that is near to the auto but only a little further back.